# Getting an Error while encountering a non Zip file

Tags: python, zip

I wanted to get the comment data of Zip files from an entire folder, but when ever it encounters any other file besides a Zip file it gives me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New
>   folder\ec5.py", line 11, in 
>       with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as testzip:   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1200, in **init**
>       self._RealGetContents()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1267, in _RealGetContents
>       raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Is it possible to fix it useing anything along the lines of:

```
try:

exception
```

This is the code:

```
import os

import unicodedata

from zipfile import ZipFile
rootFolder = u"C:/Users/user/Desktop/archives/"

zipfiles = [os.path.join(rootFolder, f) for f in os.listdir(rootFolder)]
for zfile in zipfiles:
    print("Opening: {}".format(zfile))
    with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as testzip:
        print(testzip.comment) # comment for entire zip
        l = testzip.infolist() #list all files in archive
        for finfo in l:
            # per file/directory comments
            print("{}:{}".format(finfo.filename, finfo.comment))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for zfile in zipfiles:
    print("Opening: {}".format(zfile))
    try:
        with ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as testzip:
            print(testzip.comment) # comment for entire zip
            l = testzip.infolist() #list all files in archive
            for finfo in l:
                # per file/directory comments
                print("{}:{}".format(finfo.filename, finfo.comment))
    except BadZipFile:
        print("Bad file:", zfile)
```

you may need to import BadZipFile exception from zipfile

You can also use catch-all exception but I would discourage it as it may hide other errors there:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: how would i go about importing an exception?
implementing your fix basically goes through the entire folder reading each file name without listing the zip file comment, i think you are right about importing the exception

Comment: also  gives this error after it finishes going through the entire folder(this is only the last line of the error, didn't have enough space for it):
NameError: name 'BadZipFile' is not defined

Comment: alright i managed the error yet it still only lists the names without the comment of the zipfile, maybe it's the indentation?

Comment: it was the indentation ^^ Thanks